# Seems double flagging is possible in Triage

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, triage

Whilst looking at a question on the 'triage' review queue, I felt the question was unsalvageable (no code, two lines, "i want you to tell me how to do x").

I clicked on the link, intending to flag, and flagged the question.

When I returned to the review queue and clicked "Unsalvageable", the same prompts (regarding flag type) popped up.

Did I flag it twice? This might be a problem (both for me getting double chances to flag, and also using two flags from my '11' today.)

Side note: why 11 flags available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system won't allow you to flag for the same *thing* twice, but under certain circumstances, you can flag the same *post* twice (for different things).

You can check the flag status on your profile page to see if you *actually* flagged the post twice. If you were able to cast the same flag twice, that would actually be a bug.

As far as your available flags count:

> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may
>   increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
>
> You are awarded additional
>   bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net
>   helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

From: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: +1 about the last point with the number of flags increasing with reputation: I have 10 flags available on Meta but 40 on the main site.

Comment: _You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation._ That's not quite clear to me. I have only ~900 rep, yet I have 20 flags / day ?

Comment: @JonasCz "You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags)."