# Please let me mark something I've already flagged as Unsalvageable in the Triage queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, triage

Trying out the new Triage queue, I came across a post I'd flagged a few minutes before. I tried to mark it "Unsalvageable". However, since the Unsalvageable choice brings up the "flag post" dialog, I could not mark it Unsalvageable and had to settle for Should Be Improved.

Please make it so that we can select Unsalvageable even if we have already flagged the post.

Note that the question [Seems double flagging is possible in Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278417/seems-double-flagging-is-possible-in-triage) also describes this problem, but this is a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: Or possibly don't show a post you have cast a flag on?  Sort of like how you shouldn't see questions in the close vote queue you've already voted on.

Comment: Why didn't you skip it rather than clicking something you didn't agree with?

Comment: @davidism I should have skipped it. Not being able to choose Unsalvageable threw me for a loop

Comment: Here's the thing: *flagging the post basically marks it as 'unsalvageable' anyway, and your flag reason **should have been identical*** to the one you raised a few minutes earlier on the same post ***if you have been flagging correctly.*** I agree with Troyen that posts you have already flagged should *never* appear in the Triage review queue for you. It's early days for the queue and bugs like this is the exact reason the trial is being run instead of it going straight into the 'main stage'.

Comment: Declining, as the solution here is to not show you things you've already flagged.