# If I've already voted to close a question that comes up in the Triage queue, I can't mark it as "unsalvageable"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close, triage

I came across a question in the Triage queue that I'd already voted to close through a different queue. As it was still unsalvageable, I clicked the relevant button, but I was simply greeted with a relatively sparse flag dialog box.

[image]

1. I don't think I should be able to see posts I've already voted to close in the Triage queue at all. I've already stated my opinion about this particular post, don't show me the question another time.
2. If the system is left as-is, give me the option to mark a question as unsalvageable even though I've already voted to close it.
3. If neither of these are valid options, what is the recommended action to take in this situation? Should I skip the question, or should I mark it as "Should Be Improved"?

See also [this related but not quite equivalent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278609/please-let-me-mark-something-ive-already-flagged-as-unsalvageable-in-the-triage) about already-flagged posts coming up in triage.

---

To clarify, I wasn't out of close votes when I ran into this problem. I was still able to vote to close other questions in the Triage queue that I hadn't already voted to close on.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I was *not* out of close votes.

Comment: Very funny I just had a very similar event just a couple of hours ago and also thought of posting on meta... With me it was a question I had flagged in "Triage" that later popped up in the "First posts" queue. The dialog said "You have already raised this kind of flag on the post" and so I resorted to DV

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of now, you'll no longer be shown questions you've previously flagged or voted to close when reviewing in the Triage queue.

There's a [potential loophole here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278417/seems-double-flagging-is-possible-in-triage) if you're absolutely determined to go out of your way to flag something both in *and* out of review, but under normal circumstances there's no reason to do that (and it doesn't grant you any advantages if you do).

Comment: Is [this related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308752/late-answer-already-flagged-as-not-an-answer/308763?noredirect=1#comment262896_308763)? I assumed the *don't show questions you already flagged* should also be true for audits?