# Late answer already flagged as "Not an answer"

Tags: bug, flags, review-audits

Just failed this audit https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9971047
I have flagged this as "not an answer" already but came up as an audit, so I ticked *"No Action Needed"* (as it was flagged already).

How should I handle something like this next time?

**Edit:** to clarify it further: I wanted to flag it but on the flagging pop-up section the options were inactive, and it indicated that I have already flagged it.

Comment: It shouldn't have been flagged as "not an answer" in the first place as it *is* an answer, albeit, a very poor one. *"How should I handle something like this next time?"* downvote it as you could have done to begin with. If it should have been flagged as "not an answer" and you did previously, as is halfway the case here, then you can simply skip it, downvote, or leave a comment, and move on

Comment: See also: [There is no shame in using skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Answer (score 5):

You should always flag the post as if you would have seen it for the first time. So you are not supposed to *remember* any moderation action you already executed when you review items from a queue.
The actions you choose are based on this occurrence of the post. You can't however chose the same action again. You either skip in that case or use a different action. By no means click *no action needed* because that will make you fail the audit.

<s>When you're presented with a review item it should never be an item you already acted on. So when you get a review that you know has already been flagged by you, you can almost be sure it is an audit. You pay extra attention, for example by visiting the question in a new tab. In this case you would have noticed the answer was gone, so the appropriate action should be: flag, down vote. And that is similar to what you flagged before.</s>

Above seems to be invalid due to something I believe is [a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286415/578411)

Comment: It was flagged already, the action was inactive, I couldn't flag it again#

Comment: @benka Hmm, I didn't realize that. I left a comment [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286415/578411) to get a confirmation or a better explanation of what you're seeing.